# How to remove unit separator character in "stimulsoft report viewer" when export to text?

Tags: report, reporting, reportviewer, stimulsoft, reportgenerator

there is Unit Separator character when I save as Text stimulsoft report in "report viewer" . If I save report in other formats like psf,word,etc everything is ok but when i save in Text,
there are unit separator character in it for each new Page, but I do not want to see it and i want the results shown continuously without any separation. how can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to export to CSV. There is a Skip Column Headers option in the export settings.